# How can you skip over user-defined breakpoints in .NET?

Tags: .net

I have an assembly compiled in debug mode, with `DEBUG` defined. If I execute this directly, from the command line, a window will pop up saying a user-defined breakpoint was encountered. How can I ignore these or have them close automatically without stopping the program?

I noticed that when I run a whole batch of programs like this from `msbuild`, with `CallTargets` and `RunEachTargetSeparately="true"`, the dialogs pop up, but then automatically go away. So I know there's a way to do this, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm looking for a way to do this that doesn't require changing the assembly or recompiling.

Comment: These aren't just "user-defined" breakpoints. They are calls to [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx) or `Launch`.

Comment: You need to decompile the assembly using `ildasm.exe` and remove those `Debugger.Break();`(s) from the generated code manualy, then remove any signatures and recompile it by `ilasm`. if you interesting this, i can provide you an example

Answer (score 1):

If you have to run in dbg and you have access to the source code you can add checks to see if a debugger is attached before breaking

e.g.

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached())
           Debugger.Break()
```